# SVN - svn cleanup before every svn update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I update some svn repositories daily using `svn update` command as part of a batch process. It works well, but some repositories frequently require `svn cleanup` due to some lock or conflict. These locks or conflicts are removed when I run the `cleanup` manually on each repository.

Since this is getting tedious, I updated the batch process to run:

```
svn cleanup .
svn update .
```

I want to know if requiring `cleanup` every time before an `update` is a good practice or not.

Having a `cleanup` before `update` is actually working well, but I am still not sure if this is effective.

---

**EDIT**: I am really sorry, I misstated that we share working copies. We all have our own local working copies on our own machines. One guy is onsite and two of us offshore.

Updates the repository are done both by us and by the onsite guy. I update repositories daily since there is almost always some or other update either from onsite or my colleague.

I think my locking issues are due to [internal subversion locks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html) and not due to some user locking the repositories themselves.

The error I used to get:

```
svn_update_2013-5-2-12-25-11.log:21:svn: E155004: 'C:\TRUNK\Decrypt' is already locked.
svn_update_2013-5-2-12-25-11.log:22:svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest finding the root cause for the lock and [why operations are not complete](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cleanup.html)d.
You wrote "I update some svn repositories daily" are these local working copies or are you sharing working copies (e.g. over a network). This might already be one root cause.

**Update**: Since you confirmed that you are sharing the repository via network, I suggest you read this [chapter of the svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html) (make sure you read the the version which corresponds to the svn version in use).
As @alroc indicated in the comments, each of the developers should have their own working copy instead of one shared via network.

Comment: I am sharing work copies over the network with three other programmers.

Comment: +1 for recommending finding the root cause. If the architecture you are working with doesn't support private working copies, start there. Building up automated systems to support a poor practice will likely cause more pain down the track.

Comment: @Animesh - Sharing working copies over the network with other users is not supported (and depending on how the file sharing is configured, **will** break - as you have discovered), and is also a Subversion anti-practice (you lose many of the benefits Subversion provides, including each programmer being personally accountable for their work). Each user needs their own independent working copy, preferably on their workstation.

Comment: Maybe I am saying it wrong but by sharing working copies I mean. All of us do our own individual checkouts. We don't copy over checked out repositories to other machines.

Comment: Accepting this answer even though my problem isn't solved because I admit that I am in troubled waters to boot with. (automating instead of using CI)